# why won't my json return properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, get

I am clearly missing a simple step in trying to teach myself $.ajax with $.each. I am just running this locally. Nothing fancy, just trying to understand some new concepts.

I have a .json file that I am retrieving using $.ajax with 2 objects in an array.

If I have just a single object in a .json file, I can get the return that I want no problem. However if I add a second object, and try to use $.each to go through the file, my program jumps to the .fail() portion of my code.

My .json file and my $.ajax code are as follows.
Thank you in advance.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name" : "James",
    "drink" : "Coffee"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name" : "Joey",
    "drink" : "Diet Coke"
  },
];
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $orders = $('#orders');

   $.ajax({
     url: "data/orders.json",
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json'
   })
    .done(
     function(data) {    
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
         $orders.append('<li>Name: ' + data.name + ', ' + data.drink + '</li>');
         });
        }
    )
    .fail(
        function() {
            alert("Failure");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Remove comma `},` at the end of `.json` file, together with `;`.  You can validate it here - http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name" : "James",
    "drink" : "Coffee"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name" : "Joey",
    "drink" : "Diet Coke"
  }, <-- remove this comma
]; <-- remove this ';' also
```

also you need to write

```
$orders.append('<li>Name: ' + data[i].name + ', ' + data[i].drink + '</li>');
```

because, `data` is the whole array so to access any item you need to do via `data[i]`. Actually,
`data[i]` and `item` are equivalent.

or

```
$orders.append('<li>Name: ' + item.name + ', ' + item.drink + '</li>');
```

Comment: `;` should also be removed

Comment: Thank you. I removed the "," and ";" which then returned undefined. So I changed my code to return data[i].name and data[i].drink. It worked, but I thought jQuery was supposed to handle the i for me? Any ideas on why that happened?